# Windows won't boot from bootloader; prefers GRUB instead

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, bootmgr

I was messing around with Ubuntu, installed it, decided to delete it. Now, I have a problem. I tried using `bcdedit /set {bootmgr}` to set the boot manager back to Windows, **but it keeps booting from grub!**

Is there a fix for this?

Computer: Lenovo Thinkcentre M900z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I answered my own question in a panic.

- `Diskpart`
- `Select Volume 4` (Replace 4 with the partition labeled `SYSTEM`)
- `assign letter=Z`
- `exit`
- Open a new CMD window and type `Z:`
- `cd EFI`
- As a precaution use `dir` to make sure you know you're in the EFI partition.
- `rmdir ubuntu`  (replace ubuntu with the installation you want gone)
- Restart Windows.

Just like that, Windows Boot Manager took over right away. I haven't had any issues on the subject.